# set ActionLink routeValues dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm working on reading a value from textBox (let it be Sam):

```
 <%=  Html.TextBox("Name")%>
```

and then on click of action link:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit",routeValues %>
```

I need to route (this URL should open) */Edit/Sam*

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using any route values above and instead just the name of the textbox you can just create a link
Name your textbox "name" (if it isn't already) via the html attributes new {id="name"} (for ex)
then you can just jQuery to get the value and append it

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit")' + $('#name').val()">Edit</a>
```

You could also use the html help above and just attach an onclick event handler for jQuery as well.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#name").click(function() {
            window.location.href= $('#idOfLinkHref').attr('href') + '/' +  $('#name').val()
        });
    });
```

something like that anyways off the top of my head.

There are a lot of ways to do this - these are just a couple ideas.