# Dynamic Ajax ActionLink RouteValues

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have an ActionLink link this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete it!", "Delete", new {id = getTheID}, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Really?", HttpMethod = "Delete", UpdateTargetId = "ddlRoles" })
```

and I want to insert the route value "id" on click.
The value I want to read from is a drop-down list, so I got something like this in javascript to get the value:

```
$('#ddlRoles :selected').val()
```

I already read this post
[set ActionLink routeValues dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837851/set-actionlink-routevalues-dynamically)
but I'm not sure how the syntax should look like, can someone help me?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the OnBegin overload of the ajax options.  One of the parameters passed in is the request object.

You could pull the value out of the dropdownlist there and amend the Url.

```
function onBegin(xhr, request)
{
     request.url = "@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")/" + $("ddl").val();
}
```

HTH

Si

Comment: be careful here. Your url may have various params added to it, ex. X-Requested-With and the above code blows that away (also the cache busting values it adds to the url query portion as well would be eliminated here).  I would either do a pattern replace on it or append values: ex request.url += '&search=' + $("#search").val();

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old post, but I was just looking for a similar solution.  Based on Slicksim's answer above and the comment from Adam Tuliper, I implemented the below solution using the data- attribute to allow for a repeatably used javascript function.  So I thought I would post to help others.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me", "ActionName", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "TargetID", OnBegin = "updateHref" }, new { data_dependentid = "DependentFieldName" })

<script>
        function updateHref(xhr, request) {
            var requester = $(this);
            var dependentid = $('#' + requester.attr('data-dependentid')).val();
            var requestParams = request.url.split('?');
            request.url = requestParams[0] + '/' + dependentid + '?' + requestParams[1];
        }
</script>
```